# how do i get an activity to restart but not re-create?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Here is the scenario:

I have two Activities. Lets name them `Activity A` and `Activity B`.

Say `Activity A` is open. Now, when I go and open `Activity B`, `Activity A` is closed because the `onStop()` method is called.

Now, when I flip back to `Activity A`, the `onCreate()` method is called, but I want the `onRestart()` method called instead. How do I do this?

Comment: how are you flipping back to activity A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot influence the livecycle of your app like that. There should be no reason to rely on `onRestart()`. If you use `onStart()` it will always be called no matter if the Android OS killed the app process in the background.

Check out this doc for further information: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 1):

Damn beat me to it but here goes anyway

According to the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) `onCreate()` is called again if the Activity was removed from memory because the OS deemed that another app needed the memory. In this case, you can't ensure that `onRestart()` will always be called for your Activity.

Like already stated you must find a different way of achieving your goal by using the other Lifecycle methods such as `onStart()` or `onResume`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it fits your needs, I had to do an update service that starts the first time I open ActivityA (main Activity) and stops when exiting from ActivityA (not returning back from ActivityB),

I've placed the "start code" in `onCreate()` when `savedInstanceState` is `null` and the "stop code" in `onDestroy()` if isFinishing() is true